# Save Gradle JDK in AndroidStudio BumbleBee between runs

Tags: android-studio, cordova, gradle, java-11, android-studio-bumblebee

In AndroidStudio BumbleBee, there does not appear to be a way to configure the Gradle JDK that persists between full builds of the target app.  Our app requires JDK 8 and Gradle requires JDK 11...

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

We develop our Cordova webapp (JS/CSS) on Mac for desktop first and then port to mobile.  We do full builds, not incrementals.

Changing org.gradle.java.home does not work and might be too late as the JDK is already launched to run Gradle and parse org.gradle.java.home.

Changing JAVA_HOME sets the JDK for both our app and Gradle... and all other projects that use Java.

Chaning the IDE settings can be done **manually**... each full Cordova 11 build and launch of AndroidStudio.  Here is how we have to set the Gradle JDK in AndroidStudio preferences... **every time** we launch Android Studio.  Looking for a way to set the Gradle JDK in the IDE that will be honored between runs...

[image]

The dropdown includes the embedded JDK 11 that comes with AndroidStudio.  This needs to be selected for the Gradle JDK to successfully build our app.  Here is the dropdown...

[image]

Tried starting AndroidStudio from the commandline, where env variables can be set just for the launched process...

$ JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home" open "/Applications/Android Studio.app"

If there are no options in BumbleBee, are there plans for such support in later releases of Android Studio.

Comment: I am not sure if this also applies to Android projects but on Java projects you can configure gradle to use a specific JDK for building: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a java toolchain specification has no effect.  JDK 8 is chosen by default to run Gradle.